# How to update multiple columns in window frame based on other column value on same window frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

My Dataframe is something like below, trying to update all column values based on the highest version within that group. I am able to update at the complete table level but failed to update the in-group/window frame level.

**source:**

[image: original-data-frame]

**expected output:**

[image: expected_data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, max_by(status, version) OVER (PARTITION BY number) AS updated_status FROM your_table
```

This should work for your case.